# Sparsest similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, sparse-matrices, similarity

Given a square matrix A (say with complex entries), which is the sparsest matrix which is similar to A?

I guess it has to be its Jordan normal form but I am not sure.

Remarks:

- A matrix is sparser than other if it has less nonzero entries.
- Two square $n \times n$ matrices $A,C$ are similar if there exists and invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}CP$

Comment: Simulposted to (and answered at) m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961899/sparsest-similar-matrix

Comment: Setting aside the cross-posting, the MSE answer shows that the guess is wrong but doesn't answer the question (which I assume is hard).